# Best way to attach/access SQLalchemy ORM instance

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a GUI application that uses SQLAlchemy along with SQLite, using Declarative Base.  I have a GUI table that is populated with a list of "MyObject"'s upon launch of that application.

If, in another part of the application I create new MyObject instance by simply calling it's constructor and without even attaching to a session.  My original list of MyObjects is detached from session such that I can no longer lazy load their attributes.  I know of two ways to address the issue, either explicitly adding the detached object back to the session or querying by the object id.

1. session.add(object)
2. session.query(type(object)).get(object.id)

Which is better and why?